# Create a multi dimensional array in swift and use the data to populate 3 tableviews

Tags: arrays, xcode, swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array

Thanks for taking the time to read my question.
I have experience in php with multidimensional arrays but i am struggling to transfer my knowledge over to swift...

The plan is to create an array like this:

Category1
-- product1
--- description
-- product2
--- description

Category2
-- product1
--- description
-- product2
--- description

Category3
-- product1
--- description
-- product2
--- description

And using 3 tableviews (1 on each viewcontroller) i would like to populate the info:

Tableview1 -- Category list.
Tableview2 -- Product for selected category list.
Tableview3 -- Description for selected.

I can populate 1 tableview using a simple array easily, but how would i:

1) Create the multidimensional array?
2) Count & populate each tableview?
3) Tie each child row to parent rows?

I really hope i am making sense and i am not looking for a free ride, just a helping hand as i am really enjoying learning the swift language!

Kind regards
Rory

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Welcome to swift user1263909

How to create an array of strings

```
let stringArray = [String]()
```

How to create an array of strings with string literals

```
let categoryStringArray = ["Category1", "Catagory2", "Catagory3"]
```

How to create an array of string array's

```
let arrayOfArray = [[String]]()
```

how to create an array of string array literals

```
let a = [["Category1", "Catagory2", "Catagory3"],["product1", "product2", "product3"]]
```

accessing "Catagory3"

```
a[0][2]
```

However this all can get complicated fast. Why not use some structs?

```
struct Product {
    var name:String
    var description:String
    var price:Double
    //ect...
}
```

use struct to encapsulate data for easy use

```
let p1 = Product(name: "hat", description: "a hat", price: 2.00)
```

lets make an array of structs.

```
let arrOfProduct = [p1,Product(name: "tie", description: "a bow tie", price: 5.00)]
```

arrOfProduct now has two structs in it a tie and a hat.
How to access hat's price

```
arrOfProduct[0].price
```

oh we could also have a struct for catagories, it can contain products as an array

```
struct Category {
    var name:String
    var products:[Product]
}
```

Lets create a Category for Clothes.

```
let clothes = Category(name: "Clothing", products: arrOfProduct)
```

lets create another catagory

```
let food = Category(name: "Food", products: [Product(name: "Candy", description: "Yummy Candy", price: 2.0)])
```

and finally we can have an array of Catagory

```
let arrC = [clothes,food]
```

now I can loop through all catagories in first table view to fill out the cell names

```
for c in arrC{
    print(c.name)
}
```

when you switch to a new view controller pass it the correct array of products

```
let productsClicked = arrC[0].products
```

then on that new view controller loop the products

```
for p in productsClicked{
    print(p.name)
}
```

if they click a product pass the product to the next view controller and so on.
this will be much easier to maintain as you get new requirments.

Goodluck and welcome to swift. :D

Comment: If this was a good answer and helped your with your question please mark it as the accepted answer. Thanks!